# Is it possible to delete files to Recycle Bin using Windows command line?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

When deleting files from the Windows 10 command prompt is there a way to have them go to the Recycle Bin so they can be undeleted if necessary?

I know MS-DOS had this ability long ago, but it does not appear that exists in Windows now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, there is not, but there is a tool entitled: "recycle.exe" which is part of a collection called cmdutils found here: http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils

It's a direct replacement for the "del" command which thent sends files to the recycle bin instead of deleting them. It's actually more flexible than DEL e.g. you can specify multiple files at once or use wildcards.

Comment: Personally, I was really taken with [binit](http://www.akiwi.co.uk/utilities.html) since it can read multiple files at once (separated by spaces) from the command line.